# How to decide whether to publish masters project in computer science alone or with supervisor?

Tags: publications, masters, advisor, authorship

I am working on my Master CS project. I would like to have this published as article before my Master ends.

Now I see 2 options:

- I try to get it accepted and published at my own (not a affiliated with my university/supervisor, more as a independent scholar). I will use a ghostwriter (Master CS, native English) to get the English correctly. In this way I will be the only writer.
- I will try to get my supervisor on board (eg. for advice/editing). This will result in a paper with at least 2 writers.

What are the pro/cons of each choice? Is it worth to get it accepted alone? Does it happen more frequently that students try to get its work accepted prior to finalizing the master program?

If you try to get your supervisor as second writer, does this not looks like 'student did research but supervisor wrote the article?'.

Comment: Has the supervisor contributed to the MSc project (original idea, feedback, solving problems, providing solutions when you were stuck etc) enough to be a co-author on you paper? If yes, you cannot just leave him out.

Answer (score 3):

As a master student, or even Ph.D. student, there is nothing wrong on writing a paper with your supervisor(s). In fact, it shows your group work ethics. You should be delighted an experienced academic put his/her name next to yours on a publication. It adds value to the publication, because your supervisor is more well known than you and others will discover your publication faster.

You should think about being an independent researcher; at the later stages of the research (e.g., as a postdoc or an academic).

Answer (score 2):

You did the work at the university, so you must publish as affiliated with the university.  To do otherwise would be straight-up lying.

Likewise, your advisor should almost certainly be a co-author, unless they truly contributed almost nothing to the work and your field has very tight authorship guidelines.  If you avoid including a person who should be a co-author, that is a serious academic offense.

These offenses will be compounded by the fact that this is your Masters project, and so the thesis document will likely be readily accessible by anybody on the internet, with essentially the same content and making it blatantly obvious what you have done.